# Embedding images in flash cs4 using as3

Tags: web-services, flash-cs4

I want to embed images in flash cs4 according to some description.
    the description value is coming from webservice.

for example->
    if the description is "Fair" then i have to display fair.png image or 
    if it is "HeavyRain" then i have to display HeavyRain.png image and so on..

```
how do i proceed.
can anybody help me out

Thanks in advance.
```

Sushma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import mx.core.BitmapAsset;
[Embed("assets/Fair.png")]
const Fair:Class;
[Embed("assets/Cldy.png")]
const Cldy:Class;
[Embed("assets/Sunny.png")]
const Sunny:Class;
[Embed("assets/Fog.png")]
const Fog:Class;

var desc:String = new String();

if(desc == "Fair"){
        var FairImg:BitmapAsset = new Fair();
        TemperatureImageId.addChild(FairImg); //TemperatureImageId is the Id of graphic symbol
       } else if(desc == "Cloudy"){
        var Cloudy:BitmapAsset = new Cldy();
        TemperatureImageId.addChild(Cloudy);
    }else if(desc == "Sunny"){
        var Sunny:BitmapAsset = new sunny();
        TemperatureImageId.addChild(Sunny);
    }else if(desc == "Fog"){
        var Fog:BitmapAsset = new Fog();
        TemperatureImageId.addChild(Fog);
    }